# Cant make comparison between two values as total 1 is corrupted and become total 2 value

Tags: c++

i have a problem. my total1 and total2 cant make comparison. my program will show that player 2 wins even player 1 score higher. so when i cout total1 and total2, it shows that total 1 value is corrupted and become total2 value and thats why they can compare. is it because if that turn for player 2 has came to calculate, they just ignore total 1 value? help me please anyone.

i = turn. I make i as odd number because it indicates its player 1's turn.total 1 = player 1's score. total 2 = player 2's score

```
if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7 || i == 9)
{
    cout << endl << "Your mark for this round is " << total1;
}

if (i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10)
{
    cout << endl << "Your mark for this round is " << total2;
}

if (i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10)
{
    if (total1 > total2)
    {
        cout << "player 1 wins";
        cout << endl << "Total 1: " << total1 << " while total 2: " << total2;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "player 2 wins";
        cout << endl << "Total 1: " << total1 << " while total 2: " << total2;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the code not shown, the code that actually assigns values to those variables. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve]

Comment: You need to learn about the modulo function my friend. bool isEven(int value) {return (value % 2) == 0;}. Also you should not repeat the same if statements, but combine them. As for the fix, more code is required to find the problem.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik hi, this is the code for assigning values

'code'
total1 = type(s4[randomnumber], s3[randomnumber])+system(s5[randomnumber]), total2 =type(s4[randomnumber], s3[randomnumber])+system(s5[randomnumber]);
          
and i have function of that. is this the prob? but the thing is, the randomnumber will always generate to another value. and when i add them, its correct. the comparison tho

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72843678/edit) your question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Amanda Something is going wrong getting from your 'assigning values' code to your 'comparing totals' code. But because you have not shown how you get from the first to the second it's impossible to help. Probably you don't understand how variables or functions work, but until you show a complete program it's hard to say where you have gone wrong.

Comment: You should learn to write functions (even if they will be small) to keep your code readable. For your snippet make functions : `bool is_even(int)` and `bool is_odd(int)` and call those from your if statements. Same for a sum function (though avoid passing it an array by pointer decay). And maybe most important of all learn to use a debugger so you can step line by line through your code and check where things are starting to go wrong.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik can you check out my full code at my github? this is the link https://github.com/infaddil/beyblade/tree/main . I really need you all's input regarding my code because I dont know what to do now :(

Comment: @john can you check out my full code at my github? this is the link https://github.com/infaddil/beyblade/tree/main . I really need you all's input regarding my code because I dont know what to do now :(

Comment: *"it shows that total 1 value is corrupted"* -- this is progress. You started by noticing a problem in the line `if (total1 > total2)`, then you refined this by seeing that the value of `total1` is not what you expect. So why are you still showing us the `if`? With your debugging so far, you should be looking at where `total1` is assigned its value, potentially leaving `total2` out of your [mre]. Show us how `total1` is given a value, then stream that value to `std::cout` to demonstrate that the value is not what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially your code is this

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= count; ++i)
{
    ...
    float total1 = 0, total2 = 0;
    total1 = ...;
    total2 = ...;
    if (i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 7 || i == 9)
        cout << endl << "Your mark for this round is " << total1;
    if (i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10)
        cout << endl << "Your mark for this round is " << total2;               
    if (i == 2 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10)
    {
        if (total1 > total2)
        {
            cout << "player 1 wins";
            cout << endl << "Total 1: " << total1 << " while total 2: " << total2;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "player 2 wins";
            cout << endl << "Total 1: " << total1 << " while total 2: " << total2;
        }
    }       
}
```

Can you see the problem now I've reduced the code? I think it is this.

You calculate `total1` and `total2` each time round the loop. But you **print** `total1` only when `i` is odd, but you **compare** `total1` with `total2` only when `i` is even. I imagine that you are expecting the printed value to be the same as the value used in the comparison, but they aren't. It's a different time round the loop, so the variable value is different.

I think maybe you realise this is the root of the problem.

So what to do about it? It's your code so it's your decision, but I suggest a *redesign*. How about instead of the loop being one players round (and alternating between player 1 and player 2) make the loop so that it does one round for **both** players. That way you don't have the problem of needed a variable from one iteration of the loop on the next iteration of the loop. And as a bonus you don't have to do all that messing around with odd and even numbers.

Not the only solution, but it's the redesign that suggests itself to me.